# Creating a login dropdown in nav bar without using JS/jQuery?

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to create a login dropdown (aligned right) in a navigation bar, without having to deal with either of Javascript, jQuery or Bootstrap?

If it's possible using pure css, is there any example for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following resource:

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

This shows how to make a hover menu with only HTML/CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm looking for a way to make a dropdown that contains a login form.

Comment: @Amine Please be as clear as possible when asking questions. Nobody would guess that there are more restrictions to a correct solution if you don't provide that information.

Comment: @KevinKatzke I've already said I'm trying to make a dropdown that contains a login form, without having to use javascript or jQuery or even some Bootstrap, since all examples I've found use them. I'm just asking if it's possible.